# connect Java Restful service to Matlab program

Tags: java, web-services, matlab, rest

I have a Java restful web server responding to web requests from web clients. Some requests are processed by C++/Java programs which are easy to integrate into the Restful web service. But for one kind of the requests, I want to process with my Matlab program. How can I integrate my matlab program with the restful web server so that it can respond to web requests.

It would be the best if the Matlab program is a restful web service itself, which means it can be hosted in a different server, so that the Java restful server can post a request to the Matlab server. The advantage of doing so is that, first, I can host the Matlab program in a different server; second, I can easily test the Matlab program through a REST client such as postman.

**Solution**:

> For any of your interested, I finally used ***python flask*** restful API to
>   accept web requests and then make calls to Matlab program

Answer (score 3):

[SaturnAPI](https://saturnapi.com/) provides a hosting service and REST API for Octave (the open-source Matlab clone). You basically upload your script and make HTTP requests to it from your own app. Below is a diagram of how it works. Your script is hosted at [SaturnAPI](https://saturnapi.com/guide), and your HTTP request passes `SaturnParams` as input to the script. Once executed, the script's output is used as the response data to the originating HTTP request. Sounds like it is exactly what you are asking for!

[image: https://saturnapi.com/guide]

Disclosure: I worked on [SaturnAPI](https://saturnapi.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question here:
[Deploying matlab app on the web using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831495/deploying-matlab-app-on-the-web-using-python)
Here is how I did. Basically I set up a Flask web restful web service to accept web requests (submit values to be inputs to the matlab function), and call the Matlab function from python